# manage mappings in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

What is the correct way to use Mappings in Spring Annotations? While submitting forms sometimes it happened that form is sumitted to **/controller_name/store** and sometimes to **/store**. How do I manage such errors. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think some nice copy and paste would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this caused by having a mixture of absolute and relative links / paths in your JSPs, and / or not considering the relative locations of the "current" page and the page you want to go to.

Comment: yup thats true. How do I manage that? Relative paths are creating troubles since a form is called at many locations like in jQuery popups etc. what is the best method to use absolute path all the time with Spring-MVC?

Comment: There isn't a magic answer to that.  You simply need to be consistent and methodical as you design and implement your page structures / JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your html form `action` tag. When it is start with `/`, your form data will go to `http://domain/{ACTION}`, when action is without `/` it will be appended to site current address.

Comment: sometimes it may happen that the same form, is called at many locations. In that case I want the post url to remain same for the form. But it fails when using jquery to load forms in pop ups. How do I achieve that? What's the best programming practice? Do I need to write the complete url in all the case?

Comment: You could always paste on the begging of urls something like `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`